# Wordpress pods io - Rest API for fetching fields information for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Hi I have created a custom post type using pods io. Whenever I hit the rest API for a custom post type, I get data for all the posts created using that post type. But what I need from rest API is the configuration of that post type.

That is I need to fetch the label and field type (ex plain text, file/video/image, wysiwyg) for that post type.
[image]

As shown in the figure above, I need to fetch all the fields information for a  particular custom post type.

Is that possible in wordpress using Rest API. Or is there any plugin which does that.

My requirement is that I want to configure fields of different types and I want to fetch fields information for that page. Any plugin which does that would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007869/1374538

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Pods::fields()`](https://pods.io/docs/code/pods/fields/) to get the details (e.g. label and type) of your pod's fields. For example:

```
$pod = pods( 'apc_information' );

// Get all fields.
$fields = $pod->fields();
foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    echo $field['label'] . ' (' . $field['type'] . ')<br>';
}

// Get a specific field.
$field = $pod->fields( 'apc_title' );
echo $field['label'];
```

Now, if you would like to be able to using the WordPress REST API to fetch the fields details, you can create a custom REST API route.

Below is a working example, which is based on the example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#sanitizing).

- The custom route I used is `/my-plugin/v1/fields/<pod>` and it has one `GET` endpoint: `prefix_get_pods_fields()` which is the callback for getting the fields details of a pod.
- To get the details of all fields in a pod, make a request to `/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/fields/<pod>` where `<pod>` is the pod *name/slug* (e.g. `apc_information` in your case).
- To get the details of a specific field only, make a request to `/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/fields/<pod>?field=<name>` where `<name>` is the field name/slug (e.g. the `apc_title` for your "Title" field).

  ```
  // The endpoint callback.
  function prefix_get_pods_fields( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
      // Get the pod.
      $pod = pods( $request['pod'], null, true );

      // Check if the pod exists and valid.
      if ( empty( $pod ) || ! $pod->valid() ) {
          return new WP_Error( 'rest_pods_invalid', 'The pod does not exist.', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
      }

      // Now return the fields array/data.
      $field = isset( $request['field'] ) ? $request['field'] : null;
      return rest_ensure_response( $pod->fields( $field ) );
  }

  // Callback for validating a parameter value.
  function prefix_data_arg_validate_callback( $value, WP_REST_Request $request, $param ) {
      if ( 'field' === $param && ! preg_match( '/^[a-z0-9\-_]+$/', $value ) ) {
          return new WP_Error( 'rest_invalid_param', 'Invalid field name.', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
      }
      return true;
  }

  // Callback for sanitizing a parameter value.
  function prefix_data_arg_sanitize_callback( $value, WP_REST_Request $request, $param ) {
      if ( 'field' === $param ) {
          return sanitize_text_field( $value );
      }
      return $value; // .. please make your own logic for sanitizing other fields, if any.
  }

  // Parameters for the /fields endpoint.
  function prefix_get_data_arguments() {
      $args = array();

      $args['field'] = array(
          'description'       => 'Field name.',
          'type'              => 'string',
          'validate_callback' => 'prefix_data_arg_validate_callback',
          'sanitize_callback' => 'prefix_data_arg_sanitize_callback',
      );

      return $args;
  }

  // Register our routes.
  function prefix_register_routes() {
      register_rest_route( 'my-plugin/v1', '/fields/(?P<pod>[a-z0-9\-_]+)', array(
          'method'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
          'callback' => 'prefix_get_pods_fields',
          'args'     => prefix_get_data_arguments(),
      ) );
  }
  add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'prefix_register_routes' );
  ```

Let me know if you need clarification on any parts of the above code. But basically, you'd want to change the prefix (`prefix_`) (or the entire function name) and the route namespace (`my-plugin/v1`) to something more meaningful..

Comment: PS: This answer is for the current release of the Pods plugin. And tested with WordPress 5.1.