# Creating multiple query parameters on the endpoint- REST API WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I'm creating a custom endpoint, that's basically this:

```js
register_rest_route( 'wc/v3', '/custom-product-list(?:/(&P<custom_page>\d+))?(?:/(?P<custom_colors>\d+))?', array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'custom_product_list',
            'args' => [
                'custom_page',
                'custom_colors'
            ],
        ));
```

What am trying to achieve is this: website.com/shop?page=2&colors=red,green,blue
You know, like a normal URL that you can add stuff to it, and also have these things optional.

This however, doesn't work.

I decode it like this:

```php
function custom_product_list( $args ) {
        global $product;


        $offset = 0;
        $limit = 9;

        $page = $args['custom_page'];
        $colors = $args['custom_colors'];
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986513/how-do-you-add-custom-fields-defined-in-posts-to-the-rest-api-responses-in-wordp

Comment: Am not using custom fields. This is WooCommerce and I need these values so I can put them inside the WP WooCommerce Query. That there is totally unrelated to this.

Answer (score 1):

try add another parametr for args, like

```
'args' => array(
            'custom_page' => array(
                'required'          => true,

            ),
            'custom_colors' => array(
                'required'          => true,
            )
        ),
```

Comment: and what does this do?

Comment: @kami not sure 100% but yesterday i have some problem with custom endpoint and continued to receive an error until he declared a description of the parameters

Comment: @kami this is used to validate the arguments.